# How to bind express http and https server to same port

Tags: node.js, express, http, https

I want to run my express server on the same port using http & https

for e.g.

**http** `http://example.com:3000`

**https** `https://example.com:3000`

Comment: Try setting reverse proxy for that port. Depending on the server you are using to host the code in that port, there are different ways to configure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding HTTP and HTTPS traffic on the SAME port in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313308/binding-http-and-https-traffic-on-the-same-port-in-node-js)

Comment: There's a reason that http and https default to different ports.  You can't have both on the same port.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs HTTP and HTTPS over same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453782/nodejs-http-and-https-over-same-port)

Answer (score 0):

You can use httpolyglot.

https://github.com/mscdex/httpolyglot

It is a module for serving http and https connections over the same port.